# Empty dict is returned when trying to access the list of tables with SQLAlchemy and flask (in Github Codespaces)

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to reflect an sqlite db already generated outside my app with a simple flask app, but can't make it connect effectively with the db I guess..

The main problem is that I can't access any table in it.

I'm working in Github Codespaces, and already tried the workaround of setting the path of the db with the os.path and that stuff.

This is how my code starts:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData
import os.path

db_name = 'evaluaciones.sqlite'
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
db_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, db_name)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + db_name
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

then, as I'm trying to just get the data and make this work, I continue with this

```
with app.app_context():

    print(db_name)
    metadata_obj = MetaData(schema="main")
    metadata_obj.reflect(db.engine)
    print(metadata_obj.tables)
    print(metadata_obj.tables.keys())
```

and the terminal's output is only this three lines:

```
evaluaciones.sqlite
FacadeDict({})
dict_keys([])
```

If through the terminal, I access the database with sqlite3, this is what I see:

```
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> .open evaluaciones.sqlite
sqlite> .tables
formulas         ingredientes     materias_primas
```

Why can't I see this same list as an output of my current python code?